# Solved - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function at app.js:61

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

**Solved**, but it still won't change the datatime format from MM-DD-YY to DD-MM-YY

I'm searching for the reason of my datepicker error, but nothing seems to work. Also, I've tried to make it DD-MM-YY hh:mm but it keeps making it MM-DD-YY.

The event:

```
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fecha del evento:</label>
          <div class="input-group date" id="reservationdate" data-target-input="nearest">
              <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#reservationdate"/>
              <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#reservationdate" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                  <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

**The header:**

```
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- overlayScrollbars -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adminlte.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sweetalert2.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">

  <!-- daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <!-- Select2 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/select2-bootstrap4-theme/select2-bootstrap4.min.css">
```

**The footer:**

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="js/demo.js"></script>
<script src="js/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/admin-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/login-ajax.js"></script>

<!-- Categoria Evento -->
<!-- Select2 -->
<script src="plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fecha Evento -->
<!-- InputMask -->
<script src="plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/inputmask/min/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- Tempusdominus Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<!-- date-range-picker -->
<script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

**The app.js** (it says the error is here, in the datetimepicker):

```
$('#reservationdate').datetimepicker({
       format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A'
   });
```

**---------------------------------------------**

**Edit**: It was fixed with a script in the footer and a link rel to the header, but the problem with the time format is still running.

**Changes:**

**Header**:

```
 <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- overlayScrollbars -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adminlte.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sweetalert2.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

  <!-- daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <!-- Select2 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/select2-bootstrap4-theme/select2-bootstrap4.min.css">

  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

**Footer**:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="js/adminlte.min.js"></script>

<!-- Categoria Evento -->
<!-- Select2 -->
<script src="plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>


<!-- Fecha Evento -->
<!-- InputMask -->
<script src="plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/inputmask/min/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- Tempusdominus Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<!-- date-range-picker -->
<script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: The error is because you've not included the .js file in the page which defines the `datetimepicker()` plugin

Comment: daterangepicker and datetimepicker are two different libraries. Make sure you're using the correct library and syntax.

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot for solving another problem too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include the script to Bootstrap datetimepicker. Try it like this:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="js/adminlte.min.js"></script>

<!-- Categoria Evento -->
<!-- Select2 -->
<script src="plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<!-- Fecha Evento -->
<!-- InputMask -->
<script src="plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/inputmask/min/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- Tempusdominus Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<!-- date-range-picker -->
<script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would like to thank the downvoter for pointing out the fact that I have not marked the suggestion as code initially. It is fixed now :)

Comment: Thank you, I dont have that error anymore, but i had another one that was solved putting your new line before the moment.min so i putt that line almost at the end, thank you very much!

Comment: pd. Also if there's any idea in the dataformat it would be awesome